How to fix the timing of a video created with ffmpeg being padded?
I've run the following command to crop a video using ffmpeg while keeping its subs and fonts:
ffmpeg `
    -ss 00:15:35.685 -to 00:15:46.696 `
    -i video.mkv `
    -map 0 `
    -c:v libx264  -c:a copy -c:s copy `
    -y copy-1.mkv

When opening the video on mpv, the progress bar shows the first frame at 7 seconds in (and I can't make it go back further) and the last frame doesn't match the duration of the video, so there are ~500ms left (and I can't make it go forward any further).
How do I make it so the first frame starts at 0s and the last frame exactly matches the duration of the video?
EDIT:
I've followed @sark's advice and that solved the problem with the video starting a couple seconds in, but the video still ends before the total duration shown on the player is reached. I've tried reenconding the audio to no avail.
MediaInfo shows:

Video duration: 11s 625 ms
Audio duration: 10s 969 ms

My player shows (after the video reaches the end and stops):

Current time: 11s 29ms
Total duration: 11s 625ms

Updated command:
ffmpeg `
    -i video.mkv `
    -ss 00:15:35.685 -to 00:15:46.696 `
    -vf setpts=PTS-STARTPTS `
    -map 0 `
    -c:v libx264  -c:a aac -c:s copy `
    -y copy-1.mkv


maybe you should do audio reencoding too, if you just reencode video, it may cause the problem

Try placing the input before the -ss times, and -vf setpts=PTS-STARTPTS after. Use MediaInfo to check durations of video and audio.

Thanks! I've updated the issue with more info after trying out what you suggested.
